# Comments stuck inside post edit, but not showing under the published posts

Tags: comments

I recently migrated my site from blogger.com to wordpress using "blogger importer extended" plugin. Everything has been completed without issues, except this one. Many of the posts are not showing the migrated comments under them, but when I check inside the "edit post" I am able to find all the comments intact and visible.

I have the comments box enabled inside the posts, and all the required fields correctly configured under the Discussion settings.

I have even tried disabling all the plugins, and even by downgrading the WordPress to the previous versions, but nothing seems to be working.

Strangely many of these comments are apparently stuck inside the post-edits and are not getting published under the posts.

I have consulted my hosting provider, even they couldn't troubleshoot the issue.

I would greatly appreciate if one of the experts here could help me sort out this issue.

Comment: WordPress *just* came out with a major update. I would suggest starting from a fresh new install of a version prior to 5.0, then re-importing all your content. It's likely that there could be issues migrating from anything non-WP to WP 5.0+.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, since I have made many changes and improvements in my website after the migration, I may have to repeat all those improvements again if I repeated the procedures, which can be a lot of hard work. Moreover I have many new comments added in the present wordpress that would be lost, so it is a difficult  decision.

Comment: To salvage it now you may have to comb through the database and figure out whether the comments are saved in the right place, in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said that you have already tried disabling plugins and consulted hosting provider, there must be an issue with the WordPress version. Would you please tell me the version number? Today, v5.0.1 has been released. You should try installing it.

Comment: Thank you for replying, yes my wordpress is using the latest version. I tried a rollback to wordpress 4.8 and then back again to 5.0 but that did not help. I even tried to delete the comments in Trash and restore them back, but nothing changed..